# Where can I find the SHA256 hashes of Ubuntu images?

Tags: security

I'm trying to securely validate the hash of a downloaded ubuntu-11.04-alternate-amd64.iso but it seems I just can't find any.

I found this site: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes
but there are only MD5SUMs on it.

About MD5's security: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/MD5#Security

Where are the SHA256 hashes of Ubuntu images?

http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.04/SHA256SUMS is not a solution, because it's not using valid HTTPS.

Verifying the SHA256SUMS with GPG isn't the solution either, because not everyone has the public key, so we have to import it with:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0xFBB75451
```

and I think using this method could be compromised (when importing the keys).

Comment: Let's go back to Q+A business. This is valid question and not a dupe (keep in mind, all close votes automatically expire after two days, so the current three shouldn't hurt).

Comment: Actually, that page is not community editable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently only MD5 hashes are [securely available](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/76089/comments/10). If you believe it is necessary to provide SHA256 hashes as well, please file a bug [against the Ubuntu website](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website).

Your report will be significantly more well received if you refrain from shouting profanities at those from whom you are seeking help.

Answer (score 1):

Please [use the GPG web-of-trust](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x547.html) to verify key validity after importing the key.

Answer (score -1):

[Ubuntu help: Installation/MinimalCD, section 64-bit PC (amd64, x86_64)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#64-bit%20PC%20%28amd64,%20x86_64%29)

Comment: This page does not provide SHA256 hashes, does not describe the normal [Ubuntu releases](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.04/), and is not secure because it is [publicly editable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD?action=edit).

Comment: thx 4 pointing that one out :\