# looking for the valid md5 checksum for "ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386.iso" file

Tags: security

After the LinuxMint incident, I am giving Ubuntu a try. I was one of the "winners" who downloaded on the day of the hack attack. So I just wanted to be extra sure that the md5 was okay, but I can't find any?

Could anyone please point me in the direction of the official, valid md5 checksum?

The title says it all: ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386.iso, downloaded from ubuntu.com.

"Should be fine" is not good enough for me anymore after what happened on Saturday. I want to be extra sure this time. I couldn't find the md5 on this site, neither in the release notes nor in the installation guide.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:[SOLVED]: Thanks for the answers, guys! It was just a simple matter of me being new here and not knowing my way around in these forums.
I ended up using lubuntu at the end, given that the PC parts are over 10 Years old. Works like a charm btw, plays YT vids in 720p fluently! Oh and I also found those checksums and am happy to report that the md5 checks out (but You knew that already)

Comment: Where does that "title" say? Why not download from the official source?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find the SHA256 hashes of Ubuntu images?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45708/where-can-i-find-the-sha256-hashes-of-ubuntu-images)

Comment: Hi there! 

Firstly, after reading your question I am not quite sure what are you referring to. On the 20th of Feb, servers of Linux Mint got hacked and the dl links were changed to the infected ones.

Secondly, Ubuntu and its derivatives are not hosted from the same source, therefore the orig Ubuntu images are safe. With other words: Servers of Canonical were not compromised, and I do not know about any breaches (I am not speaking on the behalf of the company since I am just a user here but with critical thinking it can be seen if that would have been the situation we knew about it by news).

Comment: I never said they were (infected). Although I did imply they might be. But that's what I was trying to find out. There's a good reason why the md5's are being published on ubuntu.com. The security breach at LinuxMint.com was being described as "unprecedented" by their admins themselves. I'd just like to oppose peoples "It can't happen here" attitude. We can only speculate about the hackers motives.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu hashes can be downloaded from [this link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.4/) - I would type them in here for you, but I suspect you'd rather go right to the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Ubuntu images and md5sums at [The official Ubuntu site](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.4/).

There is no reason to download it from anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Read
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto

> The steps involved are:
>
> 1. Download SHA256SUMS and SHA256SUMS.gpg, or MD5SUMS and MD5SUMS.gpg
> 2. Get the key used for the signature
> 3. Verify the signature
> 4. Check the ISO with sha256sum or md5sum

Checking the signature is the part usually left out, but in a security breach, those additional steps are a good idea.

Comment: Finally somebody who gets me. Things usually always go well...-until one day they don't.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]: Thanks for the answers, guys! It was just a simple matter of me being new here and not knowing my way around in these forums.

I ended up using lubuntu at the end, given that the PC parts are over 10 Years old. Works like a charm btw, plays YT vids in 720p fluently! Oh and I also found [my checksums](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/15.10/release/MD5SUMS) and am happy to report that the md5 checks out (but You knew that already).

The LinuxMint community has calmed down by now too. We can only speculate who was behind the hack attack. The main reasons for me to switch to linux are Privacy and Security, that's why I'm being so fuddy-duddy about the md5.